# Redirect to child route from parent route in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

How can I redirect to a child route from a parent route in Ember?

Currently, my router.js is:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('landing-page', { path: '/' });
  this.route('users', function() {
    this.route('user', {path: ':id'});
    this.route('all');
  });
});
```

I want to redirect to `users/all` route from the `users` route.

I've tried using `this.route('users', { path: 'all'}, function() {...` but it doesn't work and shows `UnrecognizedURLError: /users/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified from where but redirect from one route to another is done using transitionTo. This works from router or controller, inside custom actions...etc

```
this.transitionTo('users');
```

if you want to redirect to child route then

```
this.transitionTo('users.user')
```

You can also pass model to transition which does not fire

```
this.transitionTo('users.user', userModel);
```

docs here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/redirection/

Not sure if this is what you wanted but I hope it helps.